# fatal error: opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory

Tags: eclipse, opencv

i'm trying to setup OpenCv2.4.0 in eclipse on windows8 . I'm getting the fatal error

> Info: Internal Builder is used for build g++
>   "-IC:\Dev\opencv\build\include\opencv"
>   "-IC:\Dev\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c
>   -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\DisplayImage.o" "..\src\DisplayImage.cpp"  In file included from
>   ..\src\DisplayImage.cpp:7:0:
>   C:\Dev\opencv\build\include\opencv/cv.h:63:33: fatal error:
>   opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory compilation
>   terminated.

although i checked that the `core_c.h` is there under `opencv2/core/` directory .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your include paths are wrong. To include opencv2/core/core_c.h you need to have C:\Dev\opencv\build\include\ on your path and you currently do not.

Comment: thanks for answer .
Now i'm stuck on this error :
**c:/dev/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibopencv_core240.dll.a **

I'm using MinGW in Eclipse under Windows8 and openCV version 2.4.0 . In my lib directory for MinGW all file extension is *dll.a . 
Can you please provide me the info what should i include for lib.